# What data structure can be used for cyclic operations?

Tags: java, queue, circular-buffer

what data structures can be best for storing objects that in a cycle? For instance, I have a list of object, A, B, C, D, E， I need to process them cyclically, A->B->C->D->E, then E->A->B->C->D-...

What's the best way to handle this situation? Thanks. I am thinking about a circular array, but according to wikipedia, circular array is best used to implement a queue.

Comment: Also, circular linked list will provide dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: If that's all you need, a simple array will do. Just go back at index 0 when index reaches array.length.

Comment: Your example suggests that you process one cycle at a time, then stop, before processing another. Is this correct? If so, how do you want to find the first element of the cycle? Do you want to use an integral index?

Answer (score 5):

You could write your own - it is quite simple.

This makes any `Iterable` circular - but will spin if given an empty collection. Fixing that is left to the student but remember a `Queue` is a `Collection` too.

```
class Circular<T> implements Iterable<T> {
    final Iterable<T> it;

    public Circular(Iterable<T> it) {
        this.it = it;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new CircularIterator();
    }

    private class CircularIterator implements Iterator<T> {
        // Start the ball rolling.
        Iterator<T> i = it.iterator();

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            // We're circular - we always have a next.
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            // Will loop until collection has elements. Could be a Queue of course.
            while (!i.hasNext()) {
                i = it.iterator();
            }
            return i.next();
        }

    }
}

public void test() {
    List<String> l = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
    int i = 0;
    for (String s : new Circular<String>(l)) {
        System.out.println(s);
        if (i++ > 10) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a Circular list which is a list in which the tail points at the head of the list

Comment: "You need" is a little too strong. A circular list is one possible implementation, which has a set of advantages and disadvantages over others.